# ubuntu, netflix, vpn

Tags: vpn, netflix

Unsurprisingly netflix is running at a crawl in my home (where I run Ubuntu 14.04).
I'm not sure if the problem is the emulation or my ISP (other things run pretty fast).
So, I'm about to test that theory. Most people doing these "prove netflix is being throttled" tests online use a vpn of some sort to mask the connection to netflix.
Is there an easy way to do this using ubuntu so I can determine if my ISP is ripping me off or if the emulation is just bad and I need to look for another solution?

Netflix is running using the pipelight plugin for linux on chrome, which uses user agent switcher to make Netflix think I'm running firefox on Windows.
It's a pretty standard way of doing this, but I really would like for there to be an easier way.

Comment: What's your Internet connection? DSL/ADSL/ADSL2? Cable? Fibre? What speed should you be getting? Are you trying to use Netflix during peak times? Does your ISP have a traffic shaping policy that is in the smallprint? Is your WINE/pipelight causing any of the performance issues you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from VPN solution, you can use some tools such as the "Glasnost test" to compare your download speeds for different protocols. If no throttling activities are occurring, your download speeds should be comparable, if not identical, for HTTP apps, P2P apps and on demand video streaming services. If not, it means that the server you are accessing is slow, or that your ISP is throttling those particular types of content.

However, modern networking is complicated. Something like Netflix will have lots of servers, in many countries. You may turn out to be accessing a server that's overloaded for some reason, for instance. Big content delivery services are very likely to be geographically distributed, so things may be different in different countries.
In general I think it's safe to say that most ISP throttling should be constant and predictable. If it's not constant then probably something else is going on.